# Azure Devops - download a file from the API with a tfvc repos

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Is it possible to use an Rest API to download a file from a TFVC repos in Azure DevOps Service?
I find a lot of topics that talk about downloading with a Git repos, but not with TFVC.

Comment: Did you look at the REST API documentation and experiment?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't find the documentation for tfvc. Only for Git. I did some tests with tfvc, but probably I was not using the correct parameter for "api-version".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the REST API [Items - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get a file from TFVC repos.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/tfvc/items?path={path}&download=true&api-version=6.0
```

Here are a few points that need your attention:

1. The path parameter omits the name of the TFVC repo. For example, if I want to get a file `$/{name}/A.txt`, then I need to set `path=A.txt`.
2. You need to specify the file path instead of the folder path. Otherwise only the folder information will be returned and the file will not be downloaded. If you want to download multiple files, you need to use the REST API [Items - Get Items Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/items/get%20items%20batch?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).
3. Set `download` parameter to `true` to download the file. Otherwise only the file information will be returned and the file will not be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell and [Items - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tfvc/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) API:

```
$ADOHeaders = @{
  Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":ado_personalaccesstoken"))
  Accept = 'application/zip' 
}

Invoke-WebRequest `
-Uri "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/tfvc/items?path=%24/full/path/to/folder/&download=true&api-version=7.1-preview.1" `
-Headers $ADOHeaders `
-OutFile ./files.zip
```